# Recreating I am feeling lucky button

Tags: html, google-chrome

My goal is that when the I am feeling lucky button is pressed the user is sent to the first page of the search

How can I do that? I was thinking of using some function when the button is pressed or is there any easier way?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body >
        <form class="bar" action="https://www.google.com/search">
            <input class="search" type="text" name="q">
            <input id ="search" type="submit" value="Google Search">
            <input id ="luck" type="button" value="I am feeling lucky">
        </form>
        <ul id="links">
            <li><a href="imagesearch.html">Image Search </a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="advancedsearch.html">Advanced Search </a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u could use a js to do that:

```js
function feelingLucky() {
   var query = document.querySelector('.search').value;
   window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&btnI';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body >
        <form class="bar" action="https://www.google.com/search">
            <input class="search" type="text" name="q">
            <input id ="search" type="submit" value="Google Search">
            <input id ="luck" type="button" value="I am feeling lucky" onclick="feelingLucky()">
        </form>
        <ul id="links">
            <li><a href="imagesearch.html">Image Search </a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="advancedsearch.html">Advanced Search </a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain the function?

Comment: The function of `feelingLucky` is creating a variable named `query` which is used to select the first HTML element with the class name "search." It retrieves the input element where users enter their search query. Then, `window.location.href` is a property of the window object that represents the current URL of the browser. and plus `encodeURIComponent` is JavaScript functions used to encode URLs and their components to make them safe for use in a URL (it turns like `my page.html` to `my%20page.html`. and `&btnI` is added to the URL to simulate the "I am feeling lucky" behavior on Google.